# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar contenido de una celda concreta cuyo contenido es un CheckBox?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

Tengo que acceder al contenido de una celda en una tabla realizada con `asp:GridView` para convertirlo desde un `CheckBox` (que devuelve un `boolean`) a un `int`.
Aquí dejo el código de la tabla:

```
<code>
<asp:GridView ID="lst" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Id" 
        DataSourceID="lst" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PageSize="9" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" SelectImageUrl="~/Imagenes/1.png" ShowSelectButton="True"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Codigo" HeaderText="Código" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Codigo" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="seleccionado" HeaderText="seleccionadoValor" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="seleccionado" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="" HeaderText="seleccionado" SortExpression=""  ItemStyle-Width="15" ItemStyle-Height="15"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="mat" HeaderText="mat" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="mat" Visible="false"/>
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="T" HeaderText="T" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="T" ItemStyle-Width="15" ItemStyle-Height="15" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</code>
```

Debo transformar el contenido del `CheckBox` "seleccionado" a un `int` que se muestra en el campo seleccionadoValor. (Los nombres que indico son los que aparecen en `HeaderText`)

Answer (score 0):

Este codigo recorre los registros de tu grid y accede a la celda de la columna T (posicion 5) y toma el valor Checked que es el valor booleano. Luego lo convierte en entero.

```
foreach (GridViewRow r in lst.Rows)
{
    var checked = ((CheckBox)r.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Checked;
    if (checked)
    {
        int valorEntero = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)r.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text);
    }
}
```

Este código no está haciendo validaciones por lo que si el contenido de seleccionadoValor no es u numero, la conversión va a fallar. La intención es de ilustrar como puedes acceder a los valores del GridView.